# Error occurred when loading csv file into Spark DataFrame in Rstudio

Tags: rstudio, sparklyr

[Following code to read a csv file into Spark DataFrame in Rstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYLmX.png)

[Error occurred and could not resolve it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm0dA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error Resolved while reading a csv files into Spark DataFrame in RStudio
[Reading a csv files into SparkDataFrame in Rstudio without using hdfs,amazon web services and file path protocols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfKne.png)